# Liquibase - execute changesets only when application is starting

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, liquibase

I have simple liquibase configuration in Spring Boot app:

```
@Configuration
public class MySQLConfig {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    public DataSource getDataSource()
    {
        DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
        dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSourceBuilder.url("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test");
        dataSourceBuilder.username("root");
        dataSourceBuilder.password("root");
        return dataSourceBuilder.build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "liquibase")
    public SpringLiquibase liquibase(DataSource dataSource) {
        SpringLiquibase springLiquibase = new SpringLiquibase();
        springLiquibase.setDataSource(dataSource);
        springLiquibase.setChangeLog("classpath:liquibase/db.changelog-master.xml");
        return springLiquibase;
    }
}
```

The problem is all changsets in "db.changelog-master.xml" file are executed when I build app using maven (mvn clean install). I'd like to execute it only when my app goes up (so, accordingly: mvn spring-boot:run). What configuration should I set to achieve this?

Comment: Do you have any integration tests which start the application context during `install` maven goal?

Comment: Just simple class annotated with @SpringBootTest. But it is not the point, everything was ok when I had liquibase and mysql configuration in application.properties file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact @SpringBootTest was a problem here. It starts up an application context so leads to execute liquibase changesets during maven install phase.